# Function to count number of nodes to the left of root in Tree

Tags: algorithm

How to count the nodes which are in the left side of a root node? This is not similar to counting all the left nodes in the tree.

Comment: Traverse the tree and keep track of the distance to the root node, if you go left you do +1, if you go right you do -1, increase count if the distance is positive (or non-negative depending on your interpretation of "to the left").

Comment: Welcome to SO!:) maybe it's better to search your question on Google, first!

Comment: If you know how to count the number of nodes in a tree (see duplicate reference), then apply that on the left subtree.

Answer (score 0):

You should count the nodes on the left of the root by tracking the horizontal distance between the root and all the other nodes.
Traversing the tree in-order and remembering the current position (and +1 if you go the left and -1 if you go to the right) should be sufficient to do the job.

```
def count_left(tree, current_position):
    if tree is None:
        return 0

    is_left = 1 if current_position > 0 else 0
    return is_left + count_left(tree.right, current_position -1) + count_left(tree.left, current_position +1)

count_left(tree.left, 1)
```